# Cannot use git tag as version when creating wheel

Tags: python, git, build, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm building a python wheel using [build](https://pypi.org/project/build/) (as [officially recommended](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives) ), and as part of this, my `setup.cfg` specifies the `version` using a function that calls `git describe --exact-match`.

This seems to work fine for the source distribution (sdist).

Unfortunately, it seems to move or copy everything when doing the binary distribution (bdist) wheel, so the `git describe` fails because it is no longer in the git directory.

Is there any way to prevent this issue? A way to tell the `build` module to not move the files, or to keep reference to the git directory? Or is there another tool/method I should be using instead?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution.

By default `python -m build` does a source distribution build followed by a binary wheel build.

The problem described in the question seems to go away when chopping the work up into 2 separate steps:

`python -m build --sdist && python -m build --wheel`

Comment: This worked. And I was able to use it in a "Deploy to PyPI" workflow I made for Github Actions after adding the `fetch-depth: 0` param to the `checkout@v3` action (otherwise it wouldn't fetch the whole repo and `git describe --tags` would still fail.